# Jar compatiblity with Java 8

Tags: java, upgrade

I'm doing some upgrade work now. From java 7 to java 8, and also upgrade some jar files. How do I know if the jar file is compatible with java 8? Is there any website telling that?

Comment: See Oracle's [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).

Comment: You might want to consider separating the updates with the java update in the first release and jar updates in another release.  This would help isolate the cause of any issues.  It's a subjective decision based on the size of the app, quality and coverage of unit and automated integration tests, the number of jar files to be updated, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Classes that were compiled with Java 7 almost always run on Java 8. This is backward compatibility requirement. However, there are some incompatibilities that are documented [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198)

If there is some issue with a particular library, you should look for this information on the library's website.

Comment: This is a very strong statement. There exist some minor and rare incompatibilities, noted in the compatibility guide linked above. "Java SE 8 is binary-compatible with Java SE 7 except for the incompatibilities listed below. Except for the noted incompatibilities, class files built with the Java SE 7 compiler will run correctly in Java SE 8."

Comment: Thanks guys! I will read the incompatibility info. However, I'm going to upgrade jar files to the latest version like Apache commons, jacksons, never compiled the latest version with Java 7. Then how to make sure the latest version is compatible with Java 8? Thanks again!

Comment: @IvyKido - In practice, most jars compiled with earlier versions of Java will *probably* be compatible with Java 8. Specific issues are listed on the page I linked. See the links under *"To examine Java SE 8 incompatibilities with earlier Java versions, you must trace incompatibilities through the listed files, in order."*

Comment: @IvyKido, you will need to check if it's compatible with Java 8 on the library's webpage. For example, Release notes for v4.0 Apache Commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/release_4_0.html. They say that this release is compatible with Java 5 or later

Comment: Again, thanks a lot.These are very very helpful info and suggestions!